# JQuery color even divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the colors of the text in even divs in yellow and the colors from the odd divs in green. And after all to cpncatenate all the text from all divs into a larger one. I wrote a solution for the problem but for some reason it is not working. Can someone help?

```
 
    Problem 2
    
    
        var count = 1;
        $('div').each(function(){
            if (count % 2 == 0) {
                $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
            }
            else {
                $(this).css("color", "green");
            }
            count = count + 1;
            $("div").clone(true, true).contents().appendTo('div.B');
        })
```

The function in the script

```
<div>
    Hey
</div>
<div>
    Holla
</div>
    <div>
    Buna
</div>
    <div>
    Si
</div>
    <div>
    No
</div>
<div class = "B">
</div>
```

The html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope, you looking for something like this:

```js
$('div').map( (a,b) => { $(b).addClass( a%2 ? "red": "green") })
```

```css
.red { color: red; }
.green { color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    Hey
</div>
<div>
    Holla
</div>
    <div>
    Buna
</div>
    <div>
    Si
</div>
    <div>
    No
</div>
<div class = "B">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:even` and `:odd` selector

```js
var divs = $('div'); 
 divs.filter(':even').css("background-color", "yellow");
 divs.filter(':odd').css("color", "green");
 
divs.clone(true, true).contents().appendTo('div.B');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    Hey
</div>
<div>
    Holla
</div>
    <div>
    Buna
</div>
    <div>
    Si
</div>
    <div>
    No
</div>
<div class = "B">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using `nth-child` of CSS:

```css
div:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
div:nth-child(2n+1) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
    Hey
</div>
<div>
    Holla
</div>
<div>
    Buna
</div>
<div>
    Si
</div>
<div>
    No
</div>
```

Comment: Using the :even :odd selector, is rly nice too, but this is the most elegant answer i think. Just pure css. I love it :)

Comment: @n3ko sure you can use this and minimise the additional jQuery code to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

write `append text code` outside the `each`

```
$("div").clone(true, true).contents().appendTo('div.B');
```

```js
var count = 1;
$('div').each(function() {
  if (count % 2 == 0) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
  } else {
    $(this).css("color", "green");
  }
  count = count + 1;
})
$("div").clone(true, true).contents().appendTo('div.B');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Hey
</div>
<div>
  Holla
</div>
<div>
  Buna
</div>
<div>
  Si
</div>
<div>
  No
</div>
<div class="B">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("tr:even").css("background-color", "yellow");
       $("tr:odd").css("background-color", "green");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Welcome to My Web Page</h1>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That... doesn't come close to doing what OP wants. Besides, just plain old CSS will do it far better.